# With imager package, how to get the correlation of an image (with a kernel)?

Tags: r, image-processing, signal-processing

I have this pic:

[image]

I want to get the image named the "correlation" of this image with a discrete kernel, the matrix given below. I first try to use the `correlate` function:

```r
kernel <- rbind(
  c( 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0 )
  , c( 1,  2,  4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1 )
  , c( 1,  4,  5, 3, 0, 3, 5, 4, 1 )
  , c( 2,  5,  3, -12, -24, -12, 3, 5, 2 )
  , c( 2,  5,  0, -24, -40, -24, 0, 5, 2 )
  , c( 2,  5,  3, -12, -24, -12, 3, 5, 2 )
  , c( 1,  4,  5, 3, 0, 3, 5, 4, 1 )
  , c( 1,  2,  4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1 )
  , c( 0,  1,  1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0 )
)

library(imager)
im <- load.image("mypic.png")
img <- correlate(im, as.cimg(kernel))
plot(img)
```

This gives this gray image:

[image]

Now I try manually, not taking care of the borders:

```r
RED <- red <- 255*as.matrix(R(im)[, , 1, 1])
GRE <- gre <- 255*as.matrix(G(im)[, , 1, 1])
BLU <- blu <- 255*as.matrix(B(im)[, , 1, 1])

for(r in 10:500) {
  for(c in 10:500){
    red[r, c] <- gre[r, c] <- blu[r, c] <- 0
    for(u in 1:9){
      for(v in 1:9) {
        red[r, c] <- red[r, c] + kernel[u, v] * RED[r+u-5, c+v-5]
        gre[r, c] <- gre[r, c] + kernel[u, v] * GRE[r+u-5, c+v-5]
        blu[r, c] <- blu[r, c] + kernel[u, v] * BLU[r+u-5, c+v-5]
      }
    }
  }
}

img <- as.cimg(abind::abind(red, gre, blu, along = 3L))
plot(img)
```

This gives a gray image as well.

The gray image is not the correct result. I can get the expected result with the **magick** package:

```r
library(magick)
im <- image_read("mypic.png")
kern <- "9x9:
    0    1    1    2    2    2    1    1    0
    1    2    4    5    5    5    4    2    1
    1    4    6    3    0    3    6    4    1
    2    5    3  -12  -24  -12    3    5    2
    2    5    0  -24  -40  -24    0    5    2
    2    5    3  -12  -24  -12    3    5    2
    1    4    6    3    0    3    6    4    1
    1    2    4    5    5    5    4    2    1
    0    1    1    2    2    2    1    1    0"
image_morphology(im, kernel = kern, method = "Correlate")
```

[image]

I know it's the expected result because I get almost the same one with Haskell (except that the colors are inversed). So how to do with `imager::correlate` and manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct information is there, but the contrast is poor. You can see it better if you set `normalise = TRUE`

```
library(imager)

load.image("Klein.png") |>
  correlate(as.cimg(kernel), normalise = TRUE) |> 
  plot()
```

[image]

The problem seems to be that the LoG can give both positive and negative values, and we would expect the pixels where no change is occuring to be 0. Since the `plot` method for these images normalizes values to between 0 and 1, any negative pixels will be dark and the positive pixels are bright, with 0 values being gray.

We get something much closer to the desired result if we set all negative pixels to 0, since this will make the areas with no changes black upon normalization (effectively setting 0 as the new floor)

```r
arr <- correlate(im, as.cimg(kernel), norm = TRUE) |> as.array()
arr[arr < 0] <- 0
as.cimg(arr) |> plot()
```

[image]

You can bring out more detail by raising `arr` to a fractional power (since the plot method by default auto-normalizes to between 0 and 1)

```r
as.cimg(arr^0.4) |> plot()
```

[image]

And of course if you want an inverted image, you can do

```r
as.cimg(-(sqrt(arr))) |> plot()
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

The main drawback of implementing this entirely in R is speed. You need to get the correlation of `kernel` with the 9x9 pixel square surrounding each pixel of each channel. There are almost certainly quicker ways to implement this in R, but the naive approach would be something like:

```r
correlate_image <- function(image, kernel) {
  
  correlate_channel <- function(mat, kernel) {
    
    height_seq <- seq(nrow(kernel)) - 1
    width_seq  <- seq(ncol(kernel)) - 1
    res        <- matrix(0, ncol = ncol(mat), nrow = nrow(mat))
    c_kernel   <- c(kernel)
    
    for(i in seq(nrow(mat) - nrow(kernel) - 1)) {
      for(j in seq(ncol(mat) - ncol(kernel) - 1)) {
        submat <- c(mat[i + height_seq, j + width_seq])
        if(sd(submat) != 0) res[i, j] <- cor(submat, c_kernel)
      }
    }
    res[res < 0] <- 0
    return(res/max(res))
  }
  
  arr <- as.array(image)
  arr[,,1,1]   <- correlate_channel(arr[,,1,1], kernel)
  arr[,,1,2]   <- correlate_channel(arr[,,1,2], kernel)
  arr[,,1,3]   <- correlate_channel(arr[,,1,3], kernel)
  arr[,,1,4]   <- 1 # Set alpha channel to 1 for full opacity
  as.cimg(arr)
}
```

Which allows:

```r
im <- load.image("Klein.png")

my_img <- correlate_image(im, kernel)

plot(my_img)
```

[image]

But takes about 5 minutes to process the image!

The Haskell version seems to use the absolute value of the convolution of the image with the kernel rather than correlation, since if we change `cor(submat, c_kernel)` to `sum(submat * c_kernel)` we get very close to the Haskell image, providing we use absolute values and clamp between 0 and 1:

```r
my_img <- correlate_image(im, kernel)
my_img2 <- abs(my_img)
my_img2[my_img2 > 1] <- 1
plot(my_img2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The remaining question is how to do manuallly. I've seen some formulas where one normalizes by the sum of the kernel entries, but here this sum is zero.

Comment: I'm not sure which part you want to do manually @StéphaneLaurent, but I've edited to include a full manual R implementation (only the use of `read.image` and `as.cimg` come from `imager`). It's way too slow (though you could probably speed it up a lot in R, and a huge amount in C++), but I think the algorithm is right.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant the main algorithm. The one you provide in your edit is not the same as the Haskell one. I don't fully understand the Haskell code but there's no truncation step in their algorithm. And the image it generates is brighter, it has more contrast.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the version in my edit gives the same result as the imager version using `correlate`. If you change the `cor(submat, c_kernel)` to `sum(submat * c_kernel)` you get the same basic shapes and colours as the Haskell version. I find this a bit strange, as I would count this as a convolution rather than a correlation. The Haskell version appears to be brighter / higher contrast, but this seems to because it uses the absolute value of the calculation for plotting, and definitely seems truncated at the upper end. I'll add a demo.

Comment: The `convolve` function in Haskell is simply obtained by composing the `correlate` function with a 180° degrees rotation. I didn't check yet what the Haskell code does for plotting, I will. Also did you notice that in the [Haskell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVUmJ.jpg), some lines are "duplicated", and not in the R version.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I did notice the double lines in the Haskell version. I'm struggling to understand why they are there though. The Haskell image looks nicer than any of the others, but I'd need to read a bit about Haskell syntax before I understood exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Allan, I commited an error ! This picture is not the LoG, it's the Laplacian ! Sorry !

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ah! Interesting. Are you able to show me what the LoG looks like in Haskell?

Comment: Still wrong. Now I'm sure: it is the **Laplacian of the LoG**.  [Here](https://i.imgur.com/zonn6vu.png) is the Haskell LoG.

Comment: You're right. When plotting, the RGB values are truncated to (0,1).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that's enough information to answer your previous question correctly. I seem to have got a perfect copy of your Haskell result with `imager::correlate`, which I have amended my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes, and I checked the RGB values are even equal before truncation. Iterating the Laplacian is funny, that add new lines at each iteration.